# PHP recursive function inside foreach loop is adding up previous data within next loop

Tags: php, recursion, foreach

I am looping through some locations, and then calling a recursive function to get these locations categories and sub categories.
What is happening that the function returns data as a combination of previous loop result. How can I get rid of this, please help me on this my code looks like this.

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
   $get_options = categoryWithSubcategories(0, 0,$row['location_id'],$dbConn);
   // here I am passing $row['location_id'] to this function, but it merge prvious data within next loop.
}
```

Recursive function is below.

```
function categoryWithSubcategories($current_cat_id, $count,$locationId,$dbConn)
{
    static $option_results;
    // if there is no current category id set, start off at the top level (zero)
    if (!isset($current_cat_id)) {
        $current_cat_id =0;
    }
    // increment the counter by 1
    $count = $count+1;
    // query the database for the sub-categories of whatever the parent category is
    $sql =  "SELECT cat_id, cat_name from tbl_category where cat_parent_id = $current_cat_id and locationid=$locationId and delete_flag='0'";
    $stmt =  $dbConn->prepare($sql);
    $result =$stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $num_options = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($num_options > 0) {
        foreach ($data as $categoryList) {
            // if its not a top-level category, indent it to
            //show that its a child category
            if ($current_cat_id!=0) {
                $indent_flag =  ' ';
                for ($x=2; $x<=$count; $x++) {
                    $indent_flag .=  ' >> ';
                }
            }
            $cat_name = $indent_flag.$categoryList['cat_name'];
            $option_results[$categoryList['cat_id']] = $cat_name;
            // now call the function again, to recurse through the child categories
            categoryWithSubcategories($categoryList['cat_id'], $count,$locationId,$dbConn );
        }
    }
    return $option_results;
}
```

Comment: have you thought about changing the sql to retrieve all the info you need?

Comment: aren't you missing a return statement? `return categoryWithSubcategories($categoryList['cat_id'], $count,$locationId,$dbConn );` inside the foreach-loop

Answer (score 1):

In function categoryWithSubcategories()
You have defined $option_results as static. That is the reason behind results from function getting merged/added in each new iteration.

You can try this:
1. Remove static from $option_results.
2. Store the result from function categoryWithSubcategories()
in below line.

```
categoryWithSubcategories($categoryList['cat_id'], $count,$locationId,$dbConn );
```

This can be written as

```
$option_results = array_merge(categoryWithSubcategories($categoryList['cat_id'], $count,$locationId,$dbConn), $option_results) ;
```

Comment: You are right, just noticed the static variable. But the solution given by you is not working. But I got an idea that I have to play around this static variable.

Comment: Can you please clarify why it isn't working? Is it not giving the expected result or is it throwing some error?

Comment: It's throwing warning array_merge() first value is not an array.

Comment: I think this can happen if control isn't going in this if block. "if ($num_options > 0) {"   .   This can be solved if you define  $option_results = array() in first line of this function.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Don't worry I will do that. But I am still struggling around this. Your method worked but values changed now even recursion seems to failed in some cases.

Comment: Actually, it has resolved the issue of data merge, but now the tree is changed in order. Children's are not coming just after parent.

Comment: Please provide more details like how is the output currently and how does the expected output look.

Comment: the expected result is like a tree showing on a dropdown. But after this change parents and children's are not in an order.

Comment: You can print $option_results in each recursive call and check where exactly is your result getting distorted.